# cross compile clone syscall to aarch64

Tags: assembly, clone, cross-compiling, qemu, arm64

I have tried to cross compile clone syscall and run with qemu-aarch64

here is the assembly:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

.section .text
.global _start
_start:
bl main
b .

.global main
main:

mov x0, #0
mov x1, #0
mov x2, #0
mov x3, #0
mov x4, #0
mov x8, SYS_clone
svc #1

cmp x0, #0
bgt 1f
mov x0, #1
ret
1:
```

compile line :

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc clone.S -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -e _start -static -c
```

Check to compiled file :

```
# file clone.o
clone.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Try to run it :

```
# qemu-aarch64-static ./clone.o
qemu-aarch64-static: ./clone.o: Invalid ELF image for this architecture
```

Why is that?

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: You tried to run an object file. You need to link it. Delete the `-c` from the `gcc` command line.

Comment: Also why are you doing `mov x8, x6`? You will not end up calling `SYS_clone` that way.

Comment: @Siguza removed

Comment: Okay, now drop the `-c` flag like @Jester said.